# How to access String name and price from this JSON data?

Tags: android, json

I have established a connection but unable to access data.Help needed
JSON data

```
[
    {
        "name": "Margherita",
        "price": 170
    },
    {
        "name": "Corn MAnia",
        "price": 170
    },
    {
        "name": "Triple Tango",
        "price": 210
    }
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: No code no help. Sorry :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

In MarkLogic Server, you can use the XPath language to traverse JSON and retrieve data. Code can be written in the Xquery language or Server Side JavaScript:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc:= xdmp:unquote('{"root":[{"name": "Margherita","price": 170}, {"name": "Corn MAnia","price": 170}, {"name": "Triple Tango","price": 210}]}')
return xdmp:document-insert('/doc/names.json', $doc)
```

To get data, use:

```
doc('/doc/names.json')/root[1]/name
```

or

```
doc('/doc/names.json')/root[2]/price/data()
```